# How can I reference the affected version in a GitHub issue?

Tags: git, github, versioning, issue-tracking

How do I indicate that a GitHub issue affects version  `x.y.z`?

I could create a label for each version and use that. But the default label values (duplicate, enhancement, invalid...) make me feel like I'm misusing that concept.

Comment: I know if you type the SHA into the issue description, it will auto link to the commit...Not sure if this works with tags?

Comment: I guess you are refering to GitHub milestones, where you can set a milestone which fixes the issue, but not the milestone which is affected by the issue, am I right?

Comment: @JanSchaefer No, I'm referring to the release which is affected by the issue described. E.g. release 1.2.3 is affected by this bug.

Comment: @Duncan, ok I see that makes more sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

Everything in git is a commit, with the applied SHA hash code. So github naturally doesn't know anything of the versions you have. So what you can do is to add the SHA of the commit, which is affected by the issue. Github will link to that commit than. On the commit page GitHub acts quite reasonably: If the commit is only in one branch (which could be the branch of version x.y.z) GitHub notices that and gives you a hint on the commit page (top left says "refactor-sluggable-code", which is the branch):

[image: https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/2723/319484/86d6b64c-98c3-11e2-8627-9af2995a610f.png]

Even better, if you have tags for versions (which is quite reasonably as well), it shows which tag includes the flawed commit (same position now says "2.4.0", which is a tag, that includes the commit):

[image: https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/2723/319485/88653f92-98c3-11e2-98c2-23de42a91523.png]

(Pictures from https://github.com/blog/1451-branch-and-tag-labels-for-commit-pages)

This is unfortunately not shown in the issue tracker. So I would say creating labels for the versions is totally fine to give hints in the issue tracker and not a misuse at all.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the relevance of your first few paragraphs? Are you suggesting I should also be thinking about linking to the commit that might have caused the issue?

Comment: If possible, yes. This might even be done by some developer after the initial bug report in a comment. It's very helpful to keep track of bugs. Of course it's not always possible to track down the actual commit.

Comment: I still don't understand this answer. How to you take a commit hash on an issue?